# check that int array contains !=0 value using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, multidimensional-array

I have two-dimension array

```
 List<List<int>> boardArray
```

How can I enumerate throw this array to check that it contains other value than 0 ?
I think about boardArray.**Contains** and **ForEach** ,cause it return *bool* value but I don't have too much experience with lambda expression :/ 
Please help  :)

Comment: This is not an area but a List of List<int>.

Comment: This is not an array -.- Now is there an answer to the **actual question** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to check the inner lists or simply the entire thing for a non-zero?

```
boardArray.Any(list => list.Any(item => item != 0));
boardArray.Where(list => list.Any(item => item != 0));
```

The first line will return true/false indicating whether or not there is any list within the outer list that has a non-zero value. The second line, on the other hand, filters for the lists containing non-zero items.

Comment: Thanks, your lambda is the fastest. This I'm looking for ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!boardArray.SelectMany(list => list).All(i => i == 0)) {
  ...
}
```

`SelectMany` flattens the `List<List<int>>` into one sequence of ints, whereas `All` checks that every element matches a condition.

Comment: I like your use of `SelectMany`, however Anthony's use of `Any` and checking for non-zero is superior to using `All` and checking for zero. `Any` will stop looping as soon as it finds a value other than zero, while `All` will keep going even after it has enough information to answer the question, "Is there a non-zero value?"

Comment: They're the exact opposite and work in the same way. `All` will stop as soon as it find a value that is not zero. So `All()` is the same as `!Any()` and `Any()` is the same at `!All()`. Reflector both if you want to see it by yourself.

Comment: @Joel: Julien is correct here - `All(i => i==0)` will return false as soon as it finds any non-zero value, at the same place as `Any(i => i!=0)` would return true. The only extra cost here is the single extra negation, which is hardly worth considering.

Comment: Apologies for the brain-fart. I guess I was looking at `All` and thinking of a Where/Count situation.

Answer (score 0):

`bool containsZero = (!boardArray.SelectMany(list => list).Any(i => i == 0))`

This says From all the items in boardarray loop through all of the items inside of that and return faslse if one isn't zero, then we are inversing that false.